# Create new binary variables from single string of levels recorded for each observation

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-processing

I have been fiddling with the [Kaggle West-Nile Virus competition data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-west-nile-virus) as a means to practice fitting a spatio-temporal GAM. The first few rows of the (somewhat processed from the original CSV) `weather` data are below (plus the first 20 rows a `dput()`ed output at the end of the question).

```
> head(weather)
  Station       Date Tmax Tmin Tavg Depart DewPoint WetBulb Heat Cool Sunrise
1       1 2007-05-01   83   50   67     14       51      56    0    2     448
2       2 2007-05-01   84   52   68     NA       51      57    0    3      NA
3       1 2007-05-02   59   42   51     -3       42      47   14    0     447
4       2 2007-05-02   60   43   52     NA       42      47   13    0      NA
5       1 2007-05-03   66   46   56      2       40      48    9    0     446
6       2 2007-05-03   67   48   58     NA       40      50    7    0      NA
  Sunset CodeSum Depth Water1 SnowFall PrecipTotal StnPressure SeaLevel
1   1849    <NA>     0     NA        0           0       29.10    29.82
2     NA    <NA>    NA     NA       NA           0       29.18    29.82
3   1850      BR     0     NA        0           0       29.38    30.09
4     NA   BR HZ    NA     NA       NA           0       29.44    30.08
5   1851    <NA>     0     NA        0           0       29.39    30.12
6     NA      HZ    NA     NA       NA           0       29.46    30.12
  ResultSpeed ResultDir AvgSpeed
1         1.7        27      9.2
2         2.7        25      9.6
3        13.0         4     13.4
4        13.3         2     13.4
5        11.7         7     11.9
6        12.9         6     13.2
```

Note the `CodeSum` variable. Each element of `CodeSum` is an observation on significant weather phenomena. Some observations are missing (`NA`), some have no data but are *not* missing, some have a single type of significant weather, and others have several significant weather observations for the same day.

What I want is to create a new data frame with *n* new binary variables (*n* would be the number of unique values in `CodeSum`) with an `NA` if missing, a `1` is weather indicator observed, and a `0` if not observed.

I initially tried `tidyr::separate()` but this either needed all indicators to be present for all observations or it treated them in order; the first indicator regardless of what that indicator was, was always assigned to the first binary variable.

I do have a solution:

```
expandLevs <- function(x, set) {
    m <- matrix(0, ncol = length(set), nrow = 1L)
    colnames(m) <- set
    nax <- is.na(x)
    m[, nax] <- NA
    if (!all(nax)) {
        idx <- x[!nax]
        m[, idx] <- 1
    }
    m
}
cs <- with(weather, strsplit(as.character(CodeSum), " "))
levs <- with(weather,
             sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(levels(CodeSum), " ")))))
cs <- lapply(cs, expandLevs, set = levs)
cs <- do.call("rbind", cs)
cs <- data.frame(cs, check.names = FALSE)
cs <- lapply(cs, factor, levels = c(0,1))
cs <- data.frame(cs, check.names = FALSE)
```

Which gives

```
> cs
     BR   HZ   RA
1  <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  <NA> <NA> <NA>
3     1    0    0
4     1    1    0
5  <NA> <NA> <NA>
6     0    1    0
7     0    0    1
8  <NA> <NA> <NA>
9  <NA> <NA> <NA>
10 <NA> <NA> <NA>
11 <NA> <NA> <NA>
12 <NA> <NA> <NA>
13    0    0    1
14 <NA> <NA> <NA>
15    1    0    0
16    0    1    0
17    1    1    0
18    1    1    0
19    1    0    0
20    1    1    0
```

for the 20 rows of data in `weather` (below).

But this seems clunky at best.

**Am I overlooking a simpler way to create the binary variables?**

Expected output also included as `dput()ed` code at the end.

```
weather <- structure(list(Station = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Date = structure(c(13634, 
13634, 13635, 13635, 13636, 13636, 13637, 13637, 13638, 13638, 
13639, 13639, 13640, 13640, 13641, 13641, 13642, 13642, 13643, 
13643), class = "Date"), Tmax = c(83L, 84L, 59L, 60L, 66L, 67L, 
66L, 78L, 66L, 66L, 68L, 68L, 83L, 84L, 82L, 80L, 77L, 76L, 84L, 
83L), Tmin = c(50L, 52L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 53L, 54L, 
49L, 52L, 47L, 50L, 54L, 60L, 61L, 63L, 56L, 59L), Tavg = c(67, 
68, 51, 52, 56, 58, 58, NA, 60, 60, 59, 60, 65, 67, 68, 70, 69, 
70, 70, 71), Depart = c(14, NA, -3, NA, 2, NA, 4, NA, 5, NA, 
4, NA, 10, NA, 12, NA, 13, NA, 14, NA), DewPoint = c(51L, 51L, 
42L, 42L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 38L, 39L, 30L, 30L, 41L, 39L, 58L, 
57L, 59L, 60L, 52L, 52L), WetBulb = c(56, 57, 47, 47, 48, 50, 
50, 50, 49, 50, 46, 46, 54, 53, 62, 63, 63, 63, 60, 61), Heat = c(0, 
0, 14, 13, 9, 7, 7, NA, 5, 5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Cool = c(2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5, 
    4, 5, 5, 6), Sunrise = c(448, NA, 447, NA, 446, NA, 444, 
    NA, 443, NA, 442, NA, 441, NA, 439, NA, 438, NA, 437, NA), 
    Sunset = c(1849, NA, 1850, NA, 1851, NA, 1852, NA, 1853, 
    NA, 1855, NA, 1856, NA, 1857, NA, 1858, NA, 1859, NA), CodeSum = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 19L, 23L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23L, NA, 2L, 
    19L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("BCFG BR", "BR", "BR HZ", 
    "BR HZ FU", "BR HZ VCFG", "BR VCTS", "DZ", "DZ BR", "DZ BR HZ", 
    "FG BR HZ", "FG+", "FG+ BCFG BR", "FG+ BR", "FG+ BR HZ", 
    "FG+ FG BR", "FG+ FG BR HZ", "FG+ MIFG BR", "FU", "HZ", "HZ FU", 
    "HZ VCTS", "MIFG BCFG BR", "RA", "RA BCFG BR", "RA BR", "RA BR FU", 
    "RA BR HZ", "RA BR HZ FU", "RA BR HZ VCFG", "RA BR HZ VCTS", 
    "RA BR SQ", "RA BR VCFG", "RA BR VCTS", "RA DZ", "RA DZ BR", 
    "RA DZ BR HZ", "RA DZ FG+ BCFG BR", "RA DZ FG+ BR", "RA DZ FG+ BR HZ", 
    "RA DZ FG+ FG BR", "RA DZ SN", "RA FG BR", "RA FG+ BR", "RA FG+ MIFG BR", 
    "RA HZ", "RA SN", "RA SN BR", "RA VCTS", "TS", "TS BR", "TS BR HZ", 
    "TS HZ", "TS RA", "TS RA BR", "TS RA BR HZ", "TS RA FG+ FG BR", 
    "TS TSRA", "TS TSRA BR", "TS TSRA BR HZ", "TS TSRA GR RA BR", 
    "TS TSRA HZ", "TS TSRA RA", "TS TSRA RA BR", "TS TSRA RA BR HZ", 
    "TS TSRA RA BR HZ VCTS", "TS TSRA RA BR VCTS", "TS TSRA RA FG BR", 
    "TS TSRA RA FG BR HZ", "TS TSRA RA HZ", "TS TSRA RA VCTS", 
    "TS TSRA VCFG", "TSRA", "TSRA BR", "TSRA BR HZ", "TSRA BR HZ FU", 
    "TSRA BR HZ VCTS", "TSRA BR SQ", "TSRA DZ BR HZ", "TSRA DZ FG+ FG BR HZ", 
    "TSRA FG+ BR", "TSRA FG+ BR HZ", "TSRA HZ", "TSRA RA", "TSRA RA BR", 
    "TSRA RA BR HZ", "TSRA RA BR HZ VCTS", "TSRA RA BR VCTS", 
    "TSRA RA DZ BR", "TSRA RA DZ BR HZ", "TSRA RA FG BR", "TSRA RA FG+ BR", 
    "TSRA RA FG+ FG BR", "TSRA RA FG+ FG BR HZ", "TSRA RA HZ", 
    "TSRA RA HZ FU", "TSRA RA VCTS", "VCTS"), class = "factor"), 
    Depth = c(0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 
    0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA), Water1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), SnowFall = c(0, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 
    0, NA), PrecipTotal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.005, 0, 0.005, 
    0.005, 0, 0, 0.005, 0, 0, 0.005, 0.13, 0.02, 0, 0), StnPressure = c(29.1, 
    29.18, 29.38, 29.44, 29.39, 29.46, 29.31, 29.36, 29.4, 29.46, 
    29.57, 29.62, 29.38, 29.44, 29.29, 29.36, 29.21, 29.28, 29.2, 
    29.26), SeaLevel = c(29.82, 29.82, 30.09, 30.08, 30.12, 30.12, 
    30.05, 30.04, 30.1, 30.09, 30.29, 30.28, 30.12, 30.12, 30.03, 
    30.02, 29.94, 29.93, 29.92, 29.91), ResultSpeed = c(1.7, 
    2.7, 13, 13.3, 11.7, 12.9, 10.4, 10.1, 11.7, 11.2, 14.4, 
    13.8, 8.6, 8.5, 2.7, 2.5, 3.9, 3.9, 0.7, 2), ResultDir = c(27L, 
    25L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 18L, 17L, 
    11L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 17L, 9L), AvgSpeed = c(9.2, 9.6, 13.4, 13.4, 
    11.9, 13.2, 10.8, 10.4, 12, 11.5, 15, 14.5, 10.5, 9.9, 5.8, 
    5.4, 6.2, 5.9, 4.1, 3.9)), .Names = c("Station", "Date", 
"Tmax", "Tmin", "Tavg", "Depart", "DewPoint", "WetBulb", "Heat", 
"Cool", "Sunrise", "Sunset", "CodeSum", "Depth", "Water1", "SnowFall", 
"PrecipTotal", "StnPressure", "SeaLevel", "ResultSpeed", "ResultDir", 
"AvgSpeed"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

output <- structure(list(BR = structure(c(NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), HZ = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 
2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), RA = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("BR", "HZ", "RA"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You want to create dummy variables, right? Have you tried something like this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable-in-r

Comment: @cory Yes, and it would be easy if I have a single factor to explode to binary variables, but here `CodeSum` contains information on all the variables I need to create but in a compact form (only observed types are present, not all possible types). It is not enough to just create a set of dummy variables from the levels of the `CodeSum` factor. Sorry if that was not clear enough.

Comment: For the actual splitting part, you find quite a few alternatives [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988256/how-can-i-split-a-character-string-into-column-vectors-with-a-1-0-value-flag-in). The 'all-`NA` lines' are not considered there though.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
library(qdapTools)
res <- mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(weather$CodeSum), ' ')) *
                 NA^is.na(weather$CodeSum)
res
   BR HZ RA
1  NA NA NA
2  NA NA NA
3   1  0  0
4   1  1  0
5  NA NA NA
6   0  1  0
7   0  0  1
8  NA NA NA
9  NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA
11 NA NA NA
12 NA NA NA
13  0  0  1
14 NA NA NA
15  1  0  0
16  0  1  0
17  1  1  0
18  1  1  0
19  1  0  0
20  1  1  0
```

Comment: stole your NA^na, cute (though arguably odd) +1

Comment: @BrodieG Thanks, my first version was 2 line code `res[is.na(weather$CodeSum),] <- NA`, but I changed it to make it in a one line.

Answer (score 2):

I would create `cs` and `lev`, as you did, but I would create the matrix by pre-allocating a matrix of `NA` and filling in the non-NA rows in a loop.

```
cs <- with(weather, strsplit(as.character(CodeSum), " "))
levs <- with(weather, unique(unlist(strsplit(levels(CodeSum), " "))))
# pre-allocate the integer matrix to store the indicator values
ind <- matrix(NA_integer_, length(cs), length(levs), , list(NULL,levs))
# loop over each row 
for (i in seq_along(cs)) {
  if (is.na(cs[[i]][1]))  # skip this row if cs[[i]] is NA
    next
  ind[i,] <- 0            # not NA, so set all columns to 0
  ind[i,cs[[i]]] <- 1     # set columns in cs[[i]] to 1
}
```

`ind` should match your `output`, with the exception that `output` is a data.frame of factors and `ind` is an integer matrix.

Comment: sometimes a for loop is just easier +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version with just the represented columns:

```
dat <- setNames(strsplit(as.character(weather$CodeSum), " "), format(seq(nrow(weather))))
na <- is.na(weather$CodeSum)

t(table(stack(dat))) * NA^na     # Credit Akrun for NA^na
```

Produces:

```
    values
ind  BR HZ RA
   1         
   2         
   3  1  0  0
   4  1  1  0
   5         
   6  0  1  0
   7  0  0  1
   8         
   9         
  10         
  11         
  12         
  13  0  0  1
  14         
  15  1  0  0
  16  0  1  0
  17  1  1  0
  18  1  1  0
  19  1  0  0
  20  1  1  0
```

Personally I prefer the missing values rather than the nasty `<NA>` stuff, but that's just me.

---

**OLD VERSION**, full table

I don't think this ends up being much simpler, but it is in base for whatever that's worth:

```
levs <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(levels(weather$CodeSum), " "))))
dat <- setNames(strsplit(as.character(weather$CodeSum), " "), format(seq(nrow(weather))))
na <- is.na(weather$CodeSum)

`[<-`(t(table(transform(stack(dat), values=factor(values, levs)))), na, NA)
```

Produces:

```
    values
ind  BCFG BR DZ FG FG+ FU GR HZ MIFG RA SN SQ TS TSRA VCFG VCTS
   1                                                           
   2                                                           
   3    0  1  0  0   0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
   4    0  1  0  0   0  0  0  1    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
   5                                                           
   6    0  0  0  0   0  0  0  1    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
   7    0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0    0  1  0  0  0    0    0    0
   8                                                           
   9                                                           
  10                                                           
  11                                                           
  12                                                           
  13    0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0    0  1  0  0  0    0    0    0
  14                                                           
  15    0  1  0  0   0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
  16    0  0  0  0   0  0  0  1    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
  17    0  1  0  0   0  0  0  1    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
  18    0  1  0  0   0  0  0  1    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
  19    0  1  0  0   0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
  20    0  1  0  0   0  0  0  1    0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `dummies::dummy`?

```
library(dummies)
dummy(weather$CodeSum)
#       CodeSumBR CodeSumBR HZ CodeSumHZ CodeSumRA CodeSumNA
#  [1,]         0            0         0         0         1
#  [2,]         0            0         0         0         1
#  [3,]         1            0         0         0         0
#  [4,]         0            1         0         0         0
#  [5,]         0            0         0         0         1
#  [6,]         0            0         1         0         0
#  [7,]         0            0         0         1         0
#  [8,]         0            0         0         0         1
#  [9,]         0            0         0         0         1
# [10,]         0            0         0         0         1
# [11,]         0            0         0         0         1
# [12,]         0            0         0         0         1
# [13,]         0            0         0         1         0
# [14,]         0            0         0         0         1
# [15,]         1            0         0         0         0
# [16,]         0            0         1         0         0
# [17,]         0            1         0         0         0
# [18,]         0            1         0         0         0
# [19,]         1            0         0         0         0
# [20,]         0            1         0         0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let it be known that I removed all pipes from my original solution. This overlaps a lot with that of the OP, but uses explicit conversion to factor, a call to `table()`, and `plyr::ldply()` to glue it all back together.

```
x <- strsplit(as.character(weather$CodeSum), "\\s+")
x_is_na <- is.na(x)
levs <- sort(unique(unlist(x)))
x_out <- plyr::ldply(x, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = levs)))
x_out[x_is_na, ] <- NA
x_out
# BR HZ RA
# NA NA NA
# NA NA NA
#  1  0  0
#  1  1  0
# NA NA NA
#  0  1  0
#  0  0  1
# NA NA NA
# NA NA NA
# NA NA NA
# NA NA NA
# NA NA NA
#  0  0  1
# NA NA NA
#  1  0  0
#  0  1  0
#  1  1  0
#  1  1  0
#  1  0  0
#  1  1  0
```