# How to create new columns in R based on value data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset, simplified version is as following:

```
input <- data_frame(key=c(1,2),Color=c("Red,Green","Blue,Red"))
input 
   key     Color
   1     Red,Green
   2     Blue,Red
```

I want to use Color column to create extra features as following:

```
    key Color.Red Color.Green Color.Blue
    1      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE
    2      TRUE       FALSE       TRUE
```

How to do this in R? I was looking into reshape method. But seems this is a different case.

Comment: in this case, color set is very large. and color value may contains many combination as well. e.g., "Red, Green, Blue" is also a possible value.

Comment: Related: [How can I split a character string into column vectors with a 1/0 value flag in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988256/how-can-i-split-a-character-string-into-column-vectors-with-a-1-0-value-flag-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `dplyr` and `stringr` solution

As an alternative to Sotos, if you already know exaclty what Colors are allowed, you can use a `dplyr` and `stringr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

input %>%
  mutate(
    Color.Red = str_detect(Color, "Red"),
    Color.Green = str_detect(Color, "Green"),
    Color.Blue = str_detect(Color, "Blue")
  ) %>%
  select(-Color)
```

#### Base R solution

If you are looking for speed, base R is generally a little faster, in this case you can use a for-loop to handle the column creation:

```
allowed_colors <- c("Red", "Green", "Blue") # Pre-populate this
for (c in allowed_colors) {
  input[[paste0("Color.", c)]] <- grepl(c, input$Color)
}
input$Color <- NULL
```

Comment: will this be faster?

Comment: for my case, I can have a predefined Colors set. however, it can be very large, around 100+. any way to automate this?

Comment: If you want maximum speed, you shouldn't use `dplyr` or `tidyr` and instead stick to uglier but faster base R. I'll write a second paragraph on the base R solution. EDIT: done

Comment: a bit impractical but I guess `unique(strsplit(...)))...` could get you the `allowed_colors` but still I have to ask. Why load `stringr` and not use `grepl` in your `dplyr` solution?

Comment: @Sotos No reason whatsoever :'D Professionally, I use `stringr` and in my environments it's loaded by default. `grepl` would work just fine here.

Comment: @AlexR, following Sotos question, stringr, and grepl, from efficiency point of view, which one is better/faster?

Comment: @HappyCoding `grepl` should be the faster one due to less checking. If you want, you can verify that using the package `microbenchmark`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an idea via `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input %>% 
  unnest(Color = strsplit(Color, ',')) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(new = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(Color, new, fill = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup()

#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#Groups: key [2]

#    key  Blue Green   Red
# <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1     1 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#2     2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. this solution is quite generic.

Answer (score 2):

We can easily do this in a compact way with `mtabulate`.  Split the 'Color' by `,`, get the frequency with `mtabulate` (from `qdapTools`), convert to logical matrix (`!=0`) and `cbind` it with the first column of the original data

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(input[1], mtabulate(strsplit(input$Color,","))!=0)
#  key  Blue Green  Red
#1   1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
#2   2  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea via `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
input %>% 
  separate(Color, c("Color1", "Color2"), sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(Color.Red = if_else(Color1 == "Red" | Color2 == "Red", TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(Color.Green = if_else(Color1 == "Green" | Color2=="Green", TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(Color.Blue = if_else(Color1 == "Blue" | Color2 == "Blue", TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  select(-Color1, -Color2)
```

Comment: thanks for posting the answer. in this case, color set is very large. and every color value could have more than two color elements. I'll refine my question.

Answer (score 0):

I used to write R codes a lot, but haven't doing it for a couple of years. Here are some quick codes to give you some ideas. I'm sure you can revise the codes to meet your needs.

```
input <- data.frame(key=c(1,2),Color=c("Red,Green","Blue,Red"))

colors <- c(1, 2, 3)
names(colors) <- c('Red', 'Green', 'Blue')

f <- function(row)
{
    v <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
    for(word in strsplit(row[2],','))
    {
       v[colors[word]] = TRUE
    }
    data.frame(c(row[1],v))
}

df = t(data.frame(apply(input, 1, f)))
print(df)
```