# How can I split a column with dummy_cols

Tags: r, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I am using [fastDummies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastDummies/fastDummies.pdf) in R and trying to use the `split` argument. I am not getting it to split properly. Here's what I am trying.

```
library(fastDummies)

ID <- seq(1:4)
pets <- c("dog", "cat;dog;mouse", "dog;mouse", "cat")
df <- data.frame("ID" = ID, "pets" = pets, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dummyTest <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = c("pets"), remove_first_dummy = FALSE,
                        remove_most_frequent_dummy = FALSE, sort_columns = FALSE,
                        ignore_na = FALSE, split = ";")

print(dummyTest)

# ID          pets pets_dog pets_cat;dog;mouse pets_dog;mouse pets_cat
# 1  1           dog        1                  0              0        0
# 2  2 cat;dog;mouse        1                  1              0        1
# 3  3     dog;mouse        1                  0              1        0
# 4  4           cat        0                  0              0        1
```

Notice that it is finding "dog" and "cat" properly, but not "mouse". Is it because "mouse" does not exist on its own as a "pets" value? I would like to get this result:

```
  ID          pets pets_dog pets_cat pets_mouse
1  1           dog        1        0          0
2  2 cat;dog;mouse        1        1          1
3  3     dog;mouse        1        0          1
4  4           cat        0        1          0
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: I think this may be a bug. The split argument is new to the current version of the package. Maybe you should post to https://github.com/jacobkap/fastDummies/issues?

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a better package/function you recommend? The original data actually has the separate pets as a vector in a list of IDs. I put it in this format to try to use dummy_cols.

Comment: There are a few options listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988256/how-can-i-split-a-character-string-into-column-vectors-with-a-1-0-value-flag